# mpv playlist of a directory - only add 5 most recent movies to playlist (creation date)

Tags: mpv

I try to create a `mpv` playlist with 5 most recent movies in a specific folder - add to playlist (creation date).

Not successful ❌ was those commands:

```
mpv --playlist | ls -lrt1 /home/Georgette/Downloads/Bridgerton | tail -n 5
mpv --playlist=$(ls -lrt1 /home/Georgette/Downloads/Bridgerton | tail -n 5)
```

Update after comment (thanks!):
`mpv $(ls -lrt1 /home/Georgette/Downloads/Bridgerton | tail -n5)` is working but has problems with spaces and other stuff in filenames: `[file] Cannot open file 'zzz': No such file or directory`. So there is still a quoting problem.

Comment: The manpage states, the `--playlist` command expects an existing playlist *file*. Have you tried just passing the list of files (the second variant without `--playlist`)? The first command does not make any sense by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mpv manpage states, the `--playlist` command expects an *existing playlist file*. You can still make mpv play a list of files by passing them on the command line.

Your files seem to have spaces in them – which can lead to unexpected behaviour and is exactly the reason
[Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) or [similar discussions](https://superuser.com/questions/31464/looping-through-ls-results-in-bash-shell-script).

You can still try with something like this:

```
cd /home/Georgette/Downloads/Bridgerton 
IFS=$'\n' ; mpv $(ls -rt1 . | tail -n 5)
```

Setting `IFS` will tell your shell to treat each *line* of the ls output as a file name (opposed to each word). Please also note I removed the long listing from the call to ls since that adds meta-information to the output. You only want the filenames.

Note: While mpv is playing, you can use `>` and `<` to jump from one file to the next or previous.